# trouble with combining CSS selectors with a nested checkbox

Tags: css

The CSS worked perfectly fine with the old HTML, but i have to change to the new HTML (nested checkbox.
I cannot figure out how to change my CSS to make that happen.

```css
/*Old CSS:*/
.cl1 .clChk:checked ~ .cl2 {
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!--OLD HTML-->
<div class="cl1">
    <label class="clLabel" for="chk_1">some text</label>
    <input class="clChk" type="checkbox" id="chk_1">
    
    <article class="cl2">
        ..some text..
    </article>
</div>

<!--NEW HTML-->

<div class="cl1">
    <label class="clLabel"><input class="clChk" type="checkbox">Some text</label>
    
    <article class="cl2">
        ..some text..
    </article>
</div
```

I have tried many variations, but i cannot seem to get it to work; so if the checkbox isn't nested in the label, there is no issue, but i need the checkbox nested in the .

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does your checkbox need to be inside a label?  Your label doesn't seem to have any text associated with it...

Comment: Because i removed the id., i didn't bother writing everything down of course, just the key lines. added text though for you if that helps :)

Answer (score -1):

deduijk! You miss the dot at the begning on cl1Chk element.

.cl1 clChk:checked {
}

to

.cl1 .clChk:checked

Comment: Was hoping for the new solution, but you are right, i should have been more thorough. added the '.' in front of both i missed.